# Bind object's children to TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datacontext

I using `Entity Framework` to manage my connection to the DB.

I have this example object:

```
Company
    UniqueCode
    Name
    Address
```

I'll search the database using the `UniqueCode` to find a `Company` and after finding one, I want to show `Name` and `Address` on a couple of TextBoxes.

The example Xml is this one:

```
<TextBox x:CodeTextBox ...>
<Grid x:Name="ValuesGrid">
     <TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox" ...>
     <TextBox x:Name="AddressTextBox" ...>
</Grid>
```

And later, if the user modifies anything, I'll save the values to the DB.

So, what's the best way to show values of an object in a bunch of TextBoxes?

I'm thinking about using DataContext on the ValuesGrid, but I don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid x:Name="ValuesGrid" DataContext="{Binding Company}">
     <TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox" Text="{Binding Name}">
     <TextBox x:Name="AddressTextBox" Text="{Binding Address}">
</Grid>
```

Where Company needs to be non-private property.

Comment: Strange, It only worked by setting `this.DataContext=_company;` and using `{Binding Path=Name}`.

Comment: Instead of setting the `DataContext` to the `Grid`.

Comment: DataContext should be class in which Company is placed.